# How to filter an table by a value in row

Tags: r, matrix

I am doing an script in `r` that load some data from a `csv` file. SO i user these function to load my data

```
data <- read.csv("info.csv",colClasses = "character")
```

and my data look like these

```
a   b   c   d   ...
1   "A"   3   4   ...
5   "B"   7   8   ...
9   "C"   7   4   ...
9   "C"   2   5   ...
9   "A"   1   6   ...
```

How could filter only the rows that contain "C" or the "A" or both or any other string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For A only, you can try:

`data.Aonly <- data[data$b == "A", ]`

or using the `subset()` command:

`data.Aonly <- subset(data, b == "A")`

For either A or C, you can use the `%in%` operator: 
`data.AC <- data[data$b %in% c("A", "C"), ]`, or
`data.AC <- subset(data, b %in% c("A", "C"))`

Comment: what if i want to look for row that had "C" and also "A"

Answer (score 2):

if data is a data.frame, you can do

```
data[data$b == "C",]
```

to get all rows with C in them in column B

Comment: what if i want to look for row that had "C" and also "A"

Comment: The way your data is set up now, "A" and "C" in column b are mutually exclusive.  Do you mean "or"?  You could do data[data$b == "B" | data$b == "A",]  in the case of "or".  For "And" use &, with whatever your column names are. (NB you should learn the difference between | and ||, and & and &&.  Try googling for Patrick Burns R inferno.  A nice place to start picking up R.)

Answer (score 2):

In the [dplyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/) package we take this form:

```
data %.% filter(b == "A")   ## OR...
filter(data, b == "A")
```

So here it is with a real data set.  But dplyr is more about performance related tasks.  if all you truly want is to grab some rows from a small data set it's likely not the best answer here.

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mtcars, gear == 4) # OR...
tbl_df(mtcars) %.% filter(gear == 4)
tbl_df(mtcars) %.% filter(gear == 3)
tbl_df(mtcars) %.% filter(gear %in% 3:4)
```